# how to create RPM to instal openJDK JRE, PostgreSQL in Redhat linux?

Tags: redhat, rpm, rpm-spec

I need to create a rpm which install's JRE and PostgreSQL in Redhat linux.
only thing i know is i need to create a .spec file and need to mention the instruction to do this. I could do manually by installing each rpm in the linux machine , but i need to bundle this together, so that i install the rpm which inturn installs both JRE and PostGreSQL. I am new to this rpm creation. Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

what it seems that you want to do is called a "metapackage".  so your package actually contains nothing, but pulls down the Postgresql and JRE from the repos.

you need to make a spec files which will have for the 
Requires: line 
`Requires:  <package1> <package2>`
the JRE and PostgreSQL (I don't have a rh machine in front of me so I don't know the actual names), then build like this

`rpmbuild -ba SPECS/metatest.spec`

see here for more details
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-make-rpms-with-dependencies-meta-packages-720481/

Comment: by specifying Requires, does it install the packages <package1> <package2> specified in .spc file?

Comment: it means that the packages are required.  they will be pulled from the repo "automagically"